# DateTime.ParseExact() Debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, datetime-format

I need to parse a string of the format `"2015-07-16T00:00:00-05:00"`. Using the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) I have written the following code:

```
DateTime d;
System.Globalization.CultureInfo enUS = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
var result = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:sszzz", enUS, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,out d);
```

but it is failing to parse the Date string.  What is wrong with my format string?

**EDIT:**

I was using mm for months and minutes.  MM is for months.  Coming back to this question I realize that if I had tested the same format string as an output, I would have seen the problem:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime time = new DateTime(2016, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:sszzz"));
    //prints 2016-04-02T03:04:05-06:00 not 2016-01-02T03:04:05-06:00
}
```

I think it is probably helpful to have the day be different from the month, etc.  I hope this debugging strategy helps someone in a similar position.

Comment: mm and mm, MM is months, you are using it for both months and minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mm` means *minutes*, but you're using it twice - for both months and minutes. Use `MM` for months instead:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz
```

Comment: I thought zzz was for the offset? (-05:00), thank you for pointing out the MM/mm.

Comment: @MichaelBillingham You're right. I missread your input value. sorry about that.

Comment: It Worked!  The correct format was `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz` I will accept this answer in ~6 minutes.